# FTP client connection to HTTP server

Tags: apache, ftp, ftp-client, tunneling

I have implemented APACHE Mina server to connect to my local FTP client i.e. Command prompt, which is working fine. Now I want to send this FTP request i.e. FTP commands to an http proxy server (Apache http server) as an http request which will further connect to an FTP server.

I have used Apache common net FTPHTTP client class but I don't know how to implement the whole logic. Any link or example will be helpful.

My code is as follow:s

```
FTPClient ftpclient = new FTPHTTPClient("HTTPProxy",int port); //connecting to Apache HTTP server
boolean status = ftpclient.isConnected //This is returning me false 
ftpclient.connect("FTPserver",int port); //connecting to FTP server
ftpclient.login("userId","userPassword"); //Login into FTP server
status = ftpclient.isConnected //This is returning me true
```

Is this connection is is an HTTP connection i.e. Http tunneling via Connect Http method ?
my exact requirement is :-
Ftp client <---> Ftp local server <----> Http server <---> Ftp server

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: @AlexK i have edited the post put my working code ans exact requirement , please suggest me a solution and explanation.